# Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)e^{x}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, limits

Show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)e^{x}$$ diverges.

---

Since $\sin(x)$ is a bounded function, and $e^x$ is increasing for all $x\in\Bbb R$, the product of them is also increasing, hence $$\not\exists\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)e^{x}.$$ Is that correct?

Thanks!!

Comment: Be careful: the product is not increasing! Try looking a the graph of y=sinx*e^x to illustrate this.

Comment: Not quite.  The constant function $f(x)=0$ is bounded and $\lim f(x)e^x$ exists.  Less trivially, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is bounded ( from $1$ to $\infty$ ) and $\lim f(x)e^x=1$ exists.

Comment: @emma hi and thanks! I thought that the increasing criteria is "stronger" than boundary criteria, so when $x\to\infty$ the increasing function is "stronger" than the bounded function.

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

I would consider the subsequence $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin((2n+\frac12)\pi) \exp((2n+\frac12)\pi)$$

and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin((2n+\frac342)\pi) \exp((2n+\frac32)\pi)$$

Comment: Thanks! Subsequence of what sequence? What would you do with that subsequence?

Comment: If $\sin x \exp(x)$ converges, $\sin n \exp(n)$ converges as well. I was considering this sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to show this would probably be to take a pair of particular sequences of values. Remember, if a sequence converges, then all subsequences converge to the same value. Consequently, if a sequence diverges, you can generate two subsequences that converge to different limits.

Consider the sequence of values $(a_n)$ defined by $a_n = (2n+1)\pi/2$, i.e. the odd integer multiples of $\pi/2$.

Similarly, define $(b_n)$ by $b_n = n\pi$.

What is the motivation of these definitions? For each $a_n$, $\sin(a_n)=1$, and for each $b_n$, $\sin(b_n) = 0$. Note as well the sequences are increasing as well.

Then for $f(x) = \sin(x)e^x$, we see that

$$f(a_n) = 1 \cdot e^{a_n} =  e^{a_n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} \infty$$

but

$$f(b_n) \equiv 0 \; \forall n \in \Bbb N$$

The reason why your method isn't really right has been expressed in the comments already: the product of a bounded function and an increasing function need not be increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof of divergence.

If $f(x)
=\sin(x)e^x$
then
$f(x) = 0
\iff \sin(x) = 0
\iff x = n\pi$
for some integer $n$
since
$e^x > 1$
for $x > 0$.

$f'(x) = 0$
means
$0
=e^x(\sin(x)+\cos(x))
=e^x\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)
$
so that
$x = n\pi-\pi/4
$
where
$f(x)
=e^{n\pi-\pi/4}\sqrt{2}
\to \infty$
as
$n \to \infty$.